# How to get URL param values into an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an Rails 3.2 app.
I need to get the values from the URL params and add them to an array so
that I can use .to_sentence to print them out (for search).

These are my params (there are more on some search pages).

```
search=true&title=s&client=&tags=&status=&start_date=&end_date=
```

I tried this but that does not get only the values but both key and value.:

```
params.map(&:to_s)
```

**Update**

I figured out how to get the values now but I need not to map values that are nil.

```
<%= params.each_value.map{|value| value }.to_sentence %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
values = params.values.reject(&:blank?) # ["true", "s"]
```

`values` returns all the values from the Hash, including the empty strings

`.reject(&:blank?)` is a shorthand for `.reject { |v| v.blank? }`. `reject` returns a new Hash, skipping all the values which `blank?` method returns true, so this eliminates all the blank values. Note that `blank?` also returns true for empty strings.

See the docs for these methods:

- [Hash#values](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values)
- [Hash#reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject)
- [Object#blank?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F)